# Which Xap file is to be submitted to windows phone store

Tags: windows-phone-8, xap, nokia-imaging-sdk, lumia-imaging-sdk

I have developed an application using **Nokia Imaging SDK**. It builds two forms of the XAP file, one for **ARM platform** and another for **x86**. Can anyone tell me which XAP file should be submitted to windows phone 8 store ??
And should I submit the file from debug folder or from release folder and why ??

Thank you!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Can anyone tell me which XAP file should be submitted to windows phone
>   8 store ??

Use Any CPU, this will allow them to test it on emulators (x86) or real devices (ARM).

> And should I submit the file from debug folder or from release folder
>   and why ??

Release, because this mode includes optimizations not present on Debug mode.

Comment: but nokia imaging sdk doesnot support any cpu. I had followed [this](http://developer.nokia.com/Resources/Library/Lumia/#!nokia-imaging-sdk/quick-start.html) tutorial

Comment: In that case, maybe is better to generate two builds: Release_ARM and Release_x86 and upload both, just to be on the safe side.

Comment: If so,how will the device specific XAP is installed on device??

Answer (score 1):

You have to submit the one in the Release folder:

> In the Upload XAP dialog, be sure that you select the release build of your XAP

From: [Upload and describe your XAP(s)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/help/jj206723%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

Comment: but nokia imaging sdk doesnot support any cpu. I had followed [this](http://developer.nokia.com/Resources/Library/Lumia/#!nokia-imaging-sdk/quick-start.html) tutorial

Answer (score 1):

You need to set target platform as **ARM** while creating **XAP** in **release** mode because mobile phone have ARM processors so they will need XAP build on ARM configuration. x86 is for emulators only.

Answer (score 0):

The XAP in the ARM Release ie- `<Project Folder>..\Bin\ARM\Release\` should be submitted to the Windows Store.
Windows Phone Devices uses ARM based processors.

To generate the output-

- First Select Release from the Solution Configuration DropBox.
- Then go    to configuration manager and change the AnyCPU field to
  ARM.
- Then Build the project.